Number of cores in an executor and OOM error
I have read some articles on OOM error in executor of a Spark application and a number of the mention high concurrency as one of the possible reasons. I am aware that the concurrency is determined by the number of cores which determine maximum number of tasks that can run within an executor.

High concurrency: If we have a disproportionate number of cores for executors, we will be processing too many partitions. Each partition will have its metadata and memory overhead. Since they are running in parallel, they will be needing memory from the executor and eventually cause OOM errors. To address this we can set the following configuration.

from above I understand multiple parallel tasks will fight for memory in order to process partitions. But I am also aware that Spark spill data into disk. So why can't each core spill data as needed in order to facilitate un-interrupted run of the application?

Can you please provide a source for your excerpt?

Sure, this : https://medium.com/swlh/spark-oom-error-closeup-462c7a01709d#:~:text=High%20concurrency.%20If,the%20following%20configuration.

All tasks canot be spilled. Also spill is very inneficient.
BTW there is so much various context for oom.
IMO few larger executors (8cpu/64gb) tends to be less OOM prone than multiple little (8times 1cpu/8gb). In particular when data is skew, the large task might fail and be retried alone with all the ram available (1cpu with 64gb vs 8gb). Also you get less RPC network with less executors and you will save some ram with spark dedicated memory, and in case of broadcast.
Overall it really depends on your data but in general large executor is more optimal. Best is to profile the jobs to understand the usage. Can be done with the spark ui or by using a java resource profiler. Otherwise you are blind and cannot take efficient decisions.
